# How to trace who have published azure website last time?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have 5 developers who can do a publish activity through visual studio on azure mostly web app and API app.

Now I need to find out a way to trace which developer published the app at what date ?

If it is not possible then at least is there any way to find out timestamp of last publish activity on azure?

Answer (score 0):

Through **activity logs**, you can determine:

> what operations were taken on the resources in your subscription
>
> who initiated the operation (although operations initiated by a backend service
>
> do not return a user as the caller)
>
> when the operation occurred
>
> the status of the operation
>
> the values of other properties that might help you research the operation

The activity log contains **all write operations (PUT, POST, DELETE)** performed on your resources. Activity logs are retained for **90 days**.

To view the activity logs through portal, select **Monitor** and **Activity log**.
[image]
[image]

Note:The activity log is automatically filtered by the selected resource. So you could choose your resource to trace.

Here is my website trace:
[image]
You can retrieve information from the activity logs through the portal, PowerShell, Azure CLI, Insights REST API, or Insights .NET Library.
For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit).

Comment: I am not able to see this log when publishing from visual studio, is there any setting that I need to enable to come deployment logs here ?

Comment: Do they publish the same app or many apps? If a single app, change the Resource as your app's name. Also, you could click your website on portal, it has its own Activity log. If many apps in the same resource group, then modify the group name.